# ImageIcon exception

Tags: java

im new to java, and while running this on eclipse linux mint with java-7-openjdk (i think , although dont know if eclipse has its own sun jdt),

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
private JComboBox box;
private JLabel picture;
private static String[] filename = {"b.PNG","x.PNG"};
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])),   
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1]))};



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
at bucky.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:10)
at bucky.apples.main(apples.java:12)
```

I cant see what the problem is (linux mint 15 cinnamon)

Comment: check that getClass().getResource(filename[0]) is actually going to the path of your image...

Comment: Simply place `b.PNG` and `x.PNG` alongside `GUI.class` file... More info can be found on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) :-). Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

This Exception is thrown in ImageIcon constructor and states that `getClass().getResource(filename[0])` or `getClass().getResource(filename[1])` is null

The path you specified isn't correct. Make sure folder where these images are is in your classpath

An easy check can be made:

```
File f = new File("b.PNG");
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

should print you `true`

Answer (score 2):

`getClass().getResource(filename[0])` where `filename[0]` is `b.PNG` denotes a relative path and will try to load the image from the same folder (i.e. the same package) as your class `Gui`.

Make sure the images are actually at that location.

If your images are at the default package (i.e. your root source folder) you can load them as `getClass().getResource("/" + filename[0])` (i.e. using an absolute path).

Answer (score 0):

Oh human mistakes can be so mean. Instead of b.PNG and x.PNG, my files were a.PNG and x.PNG
Really a shame, but thx nonetheless.